# Aligning element to bottom of div with overflow: auto

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, margin

I created a "To-do list" page, where every new task is printed on a new card, and
every card includes a description, an hour, and date elements.

In the CSS I added `overflow: auto`, so if the **description** is long, the user can scroll down.
But in this kind of card (when `overflow` is on), the two other elements (hour, date) are printed under the long text and not attached to the bottom like other cases, even though I defined their CSS block with "`bottom: 0`".
How can I make it so that in the cards with short descriptions the hour and date are aligned to the bottom, and have the same behavior when `overflow`(scrolling) is on?

```
/* card style block */
    .tilesWrap li {
        flex: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 300px;
        padding: 10px 20px 40px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10px;
        font-family: monospace;
        min-height: 40vh;
        max-height: 400px;
        text-align: left;
        overflow-x: auto;
        }
    #cardTitle {
        padding-top: 20px;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
    }
    #cardDate {
        font-family: monospace;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        font-size: large;
    }
    #cardHour {
        display: block;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: large;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

[This is how it looks right now, long text over date and hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5k1s.jpg)
?

I tried to change `position` to:`sticky, static, relative, and absolute`,
but every time something else is ruined.
Also tried that the card will be `position: fixed text ->` position: relative`date&hour ->`position: absolute`

Comment: With the information you provided I think you can split the hour in one container and the content inside another, the container with the content has overflow: auto; the parent container not. If you want a more accurate answer please provide a working snippet.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try applying the overflow-x property to specifically the title instead of the whole card (so, NOT to `.tilesWrap li`, but to `#cardTitle`), and specify a height for the title element, if needed.